# jQuery Array Data

Tags: jquery, json

This is my code in PHP file.

```
$reciept = mysql_fetch_array($recieptRecord);
$recip = array(
             'recieptID' => $reciept['recieptID'], 
             'companyID' => $reciept['companyID']
          );
echo json_encode($recip);
```

Over to the jQuery script.

Comment: Try asking an actual question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get wat you want...but if you're calling it from ajax, you'll have something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "phpfile.php,
  success: function(resp){
    var response = JSON.parse(resp);
  }
});
```

There are also another parameter to ajax, pay attention to 'em. Check mor in:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/